# Double spacing using doublespacing environment

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, setspace

I want to locally apply double spacing in a certain *paragraph* of the document by using `\begin{doublespacing}` and `\end{doublespacing}` from the `setspace` package. However, I found it only takes effects if an extra blank line is added to the code, which is redundant for the code readability... Is there a better way/workaround to have double-spacing without the additional blank line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,twoside,fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook} % two-sided


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{doublespacing}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{doublespacing}

\begin{doublespacing}
    \lipsum[1]
                   % ---> Extra blank line necessary for the double-spacing
\end{doublespacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second example you give, with the comment `% ---> Extra blank line necessary for the double-spacing`, does *not* actually generated a double-spaced paragraph of filler text. Why? Because it's not an all-blank line. Only all-blank lines generate a paragraph break, which is what's need for doublespacing to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've discovered is not a bug but a core feature of the entire TeX paragraph builder system: The line-spacing within a paragraph depends on where the paragraph's end actually occurs. In the case of

```
\begin{doublespacing}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{doublespacing}
```

the end of the paragraph -- as far as TeX is concerned -- occurs *not* at the final period (aka full stop) of the lipsum filler text but *after* `\end{doublespacing}`. But by then the scope of the `doublespacing` environment has ended; hence, the text beloniging to lipsum[1] is (correctly, in my view) typeset single-spaced.

There are several ways to trigger the end of a paragraph:

- One or more *all-blank* lines in the input. Incidentally, the line you present in the second code snippet of your posting is *not* all-blank (since it contains a comment) and therefore, contrary to your claim, does not suffice to make the paragraph double-spaced.
- An explicit `\par` directive.
- Implicit paragraph break instructions, issued by commands such as `\chapter`, `\section`, `\begin{theorem}`, and many more. Aside: the `\\` ("double backslash") instruction induces a line break *but not a paragraph break* according to TeX's lexical rules.

Your main question was,

> Is there a better way/workaround to have double-spacing without the additional blank line?

I'd say that issuing an explicit `\par` directive is your main alternative to leaving an all-blank line.